# Parallel For-Each Mule 4.2.2

Tags: parallel-processing, mule

I am getting the below errors in the application running in production.

```
"org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain - Unexpected state. Error handler should be invoked with either an Event instance or a MessagingException
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null"
```

I am seeing this error while the app is running inside the parallel foreach invoking services.

Any idea when we would this kinda exception happens

Comment: You should provide the details of the parallel foreach and what it does, in XML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be caused by one of the issues fixed in Mule 4.3.0. Try to test with 4.3.0 to see if the issue goes away.